# How many characters should I update in the normal flow of a text editing program?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

So, I'm making this text editor from scratch using a custom edit control. As of now, I update the visible part of the current line in which the caret is contained. It works generally fine, but i tried to type really fast on it, and I notice that it flickers(only once or twice, and only for lines that are very long). But this little flicker is kinda not good.

- So, I was wondering whether I should update only two characters at a
  time(the current character and the previous character). 2 characters
  because if I don't erase/update the previous character there would be
  an artifact from the cursor in the previous position.
- I am also analyzing my code to check if there is a performance
  bottleneck or sloppy code out there. In this regard, I noticed that I
  pass a lot of `HANDLE's' to windows and stuff. I was wondering if it
  would make a difference if I pass them as references instead. I know
  that handles are 32-bit values as well, so I'm not sure if there
  would be any boost in performance.

Thanks!

Devjeet

Comment: There would be an extremely slight reduction in performance if you use references because you add one level of indirection. As for your problem, are you doing double buffering?

Comment: No, I've not done it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the contents of your editor control using [MemDC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/flickerfree.aspx). This example uses MFC, but the idea is independent of it.